# Refreshing External Data for an Excel file in MacOS

Tags: python, macos

I've seen questions answering, how to update a connection to an odbc external source in windows, but none of the answers tell how to achieve this same result in MacOS.

On windows I've achieved the results I'm looking for using the win32com client but for obvious reasons it doesn't work on Mac.

Anyone know of an alternative?

Comment: Instead of focusing on ODBC - what do you want to do with the file? There are probably other ways to solve your issue.

Comment: I am automating the process of printing to PDF a worksheet which updates its data from a shared folder our team has. The reason 'm looking to refresh the data is that on a weekly basis the data is posted in a txt file for many different excel files to use as needed.

Comment: Could [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) work to do that?

Comment: Reading through the docs and looking specifically into this, it seems like openpyxl doesn't provide this functionality.

Comment: openpyxl would allow you to open the Excel file, open the txt file and insert the values you want into the document. Printing it will have to be done in some other way, depending on what you're using to display the document under OS X.